# Can I protect a dimmer switch circuit with a GFCI outlet?

Tags: wiring, gfci, dimmer-switch

I'm installing some line-level-dimmable LED undercabinet lighting in my kitchen. I'd like to protect it with one of the existing GFCI outlets in the area. My sequence would be GFCI > dimmer switch > LED lighting.

Are there any problems with this scenario? Would I be wiser to use a different device, such as a protected switch combo or a new home run from a GFCI breaker?

*Note: I'm aware that it's a violation of code to control standard receptacles with dimmer switches. Assume that I'll use dedicated dimmable receptacles such as those provided by Lutron so we can avoid side discussion.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the GFCI receptacle you're branching from is on the small appliance branch circuit, you're not allowed to use that circuit to supply any other outlet (that is not a floor, wall, or countertop receptacle outlet serving the kitchen, pantry, breakfast room, dining room, or similar area of a dwelling unit).

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 2 Wiring and Protection.
>
> #### Article 210 Branch Circuits.
>
> **210.52 Dwelling Unit Receptacle Outlets.**
>
> **(B) Small Appliances.**
>
> **(2) No Other Outlets.** The two or more small-appliance branch circuits specified in 210.52(B)(1) shall have no other outlets.

So you won't be able to draw your power from there.

Other than that, there's no problem providing GFCI protection to lights.